# UI on different resolutions devices for BB10

Tags: user-interface, blackberry-10, screen-resolution

I have developed a static library for BB10 that provides a UI for capturing user credentials and then authenticate those credentials.

I have used this library in one of my app.

Problem I am facing is, whenever I run that app in BB Q10 device( Resolutions 720*720 ) the logo I am providing at the top of UI is not completely visible. but it works fine when i run the app in Z10( 768 x 1280 ).

Can anyone suggest what should I do such that this doesn't happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a 720x720 specific asset: logo or layout. Basicaly, in your assets folder, make a 720x720 folder. If you put some content (with same name as your assets root folder content) inside of it, the Q10 will load the one in the 720x720 folder instead of the default one. It will change nothing on the Z10. See here for a complete explanation: http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/ui/resolution/using_static_asset.html